# Play framework 2.12; running CLI jobs as part of production

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have Rails experience but I'm new to Scala/Play.
I'm building a simple Play application.  It naturally has a Web UI built in.

One thing I need is a simple admin CLI tool.  It needs to be able to run in a production environment to do various tasks such as import usernames.  It would be something akin to Rails Rake,
in the sense that code can utilize most of the Play application stack.  It needs the ability to use the database defined in the Play app.

I tried creating a custom sbt task but it doesn't have access to the 
run time play application.
Ex. Build.scala

```
val sample_tsk = TaskKey[Unit]("sample_tsk", "Prints 'Hello World'")
val sampleTask = sample_tsk := {
  println("Hello World2")    

  // this doesn't work.
  import play.api.db._
  import play.api.Play.current            
  println("About to get connection...")
  val conn = DB.getConnection()
}
```

I can't access the database using a technique like this.  I'm thinking it's because the sbt
tool doesn't really know about the play application.

Can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all an SBT expert but as far as I know. SBT is used to compile the Play app, so it would be weird to access it in a task of the build definition while it is not already built.

If your database configuration is in the Play configuration files, then your application configuration is coupled with Play framework. I think it will be hard to bypass this coupling and be able to reuse some application code of your application inside an SBT task.

But if your application is not so coupled with Play, you could eventually create another SBT project for your tasks. In this project you can add a dependency to the build script.

Here's an exemple of one of my build `plugins.sbt` which uses a MongoDB library.

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
    DefaultMavenRepository,
    Resolver.url("Play", url("http://download.playframework.org/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
    "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.2")

libraryDependencies += "de.flapdoodle.embed" % "de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo" % "1.28"
```

Once this is added, I am able to import the Embed MongoDB classes inside my `Build.scala` and call them.

You could eventually have 3 projects:

- core: most of your application code
- webapp: the Play coupled application which will depend on core
- tasks: the sbt tasks project which will depend on core

This means that you should create a core project that should not be coupled with Play. There's some work to do here.

Another idea may to create inside your webapplication a small backoffice with some buttons to run the tasks. It is a short term solution, I don't think all these tasks should be run inside the same JVM because they may need different tunning, and not slow down your production code... but I think the Play modules or plugins can help to solve this issue.

Comment: "so it would be weird to access it in a task of the build definition" -- I totally agree; this smells bad :(

Comment: I'm comparing this a little to Rails, where you can have an .rb script load the Rails stack with a simple call to require_relative '../config/environment'.  Perhaps it's not just practical do do this here.

Comment: I've asked a quite similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954154/use-sbt-to-launch-an-applicative-task-batch because I need something like this. I think it can work fine

Comment: I don't know Rake. I read the whole SBT getting started guide yesterday and I think this page can help you: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Using-Plugins (+ read the page about the recursivity of an SBT project)