# Use SBT to launch an applicative task/batch?

Tags: scala, sbt

Can SBT be used to launch applicative Scala batches?

I mean, a Scala applicative code that would decrement all the user's balance for exemple.

I can imagine a special SBT project for that with a build dependency on the applicative code, so that some SBT tasks of the project can launch this applicative code.

Would you do such a thing? Why?

What are the alternatives to ease the launch of applicative batches in Scala? With Maven I used to use the appassembler plugin which would generate sh scripts and all the classpath related stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use `sbt run`.

```
object Main {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
   // decrement all user balances.
   };
};
```

Then `sbt run` from shell, jenkins, etc.

Use command line args to expand the functionality.

Comment: Thanks yes I could do that too :) I was thinking of using tasks because there could be potentially different launchable processes inside the same sbt project. But would you recommand to use this kind of code?